# Libsvm: SVM normalizing starts from 0 or 0.001

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, svm, libsvm, document-classification

I am using libsvm for my document classification.

I use svm.h and svm.cc only in my project.

Its struct svm_problem requires array of svm_node that are non-zero thus using sparse.

I get a vector of tf-idf words with lets say in range [5,10]. If i normalize it to [0,1], all the 5's would become 0.

Should i remove these zeroes when sending it to svm_train ?

Does removing these would not reduce the information and lead to poor results ?

should i start the normalization from 0.001 rather than 0 ?

Well, in general, in SVM does normalizing in [0,1] not reduces information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SVM` is not a `Naive Bayes`, feature's values are not counters, but dimensions in multidimensional real valued space, 0's have exactly the same amount of information as 1's (which also answers your concern regarding removing 0 values - don't do it). There is no reason to ever normalize data to `[0.001, 1]` for the `SVM`.

The only issue here is that column-wise normalization is not a good idea for the `tf-idf`, as it will degenerate yout features to the `tf` (as for perticular `i`'th dimension, `tf-idf` is simply `tf` value in `[0,1]` multiplied by a constant `idf`, normalization will multiply by `idf^-1`). I would consider one of the alternative preprocessing methods:

- normalizing each dimension, so it has mean 0 and variance 1
- decorrelation by making `x=C^-1/2*x`, where  `C` is data covariance matrix

Comment: is tf-idf means tf in [0,1] or number of times that term appeared in the document ? If its in [0,1] do we divide no_of_times/total_words ?

Comment: I am doing normalization by computing min and max in the vector and then lower + (upper - lower)*(vec[i]-min)/(max-min) ?

Comment: tf term is normalized by the length of the particular document, so it results in [0,1] range.

Comment: I hope by column-wise normalization you mean above method ? Please tell me if i am wrong ?

Comment: once again - I mean, that this is a wrong type of normalization for the tf-idf. What is "lower" and "upper", what is "min" and "max", what is **vec** in fact? You have a matrix of M vectors of length N. Normalization can be performed row-wise (each vector separately) or column-wise (each dimension separately).

Comment: i am performing row-wise normalization. lower is 0 and upper is 1. min is min_in_row and max is max_in_row. i do it for each row. vec is each row. Is it wrong ?

Comment: This will not degenerate tf-idf, but instead place your vectors on the hyper-sphere. It is hard to say if it is wrong in this particular case. In general locating all the data on the hyper-sphere does not seem right for any machine learning approach as it adds artificial geometrical bias to the set.

Comment: if you mean that this would place them on the "surface" of a hyper-sphere, i do not get it. or if you mean in a hyper sphere, they are already n-dim vectors, some n-sphere would always surround it. I always thought that it is good to normalize your data in SVMs.

Comment: It will place them on the surface, if you normalize each vector to have a length 1 (which is a row normalization) it ends up on the unit sphere. Normalizing data for the SVM is considered in the column-wise fashion, and is aimed and completely different issue (varying values amplitude can bias hyperplane in the direction of feature with more wide range of values). Once again - it should be normalized, but not that way, rather - by one of the proposed methods in the answer.

Comment: Actually, normalizing row-wise is not uncommon in text mining. Instead of being a tf-idf representation, it's related to the document's histogram. Both work in practice, but tf-idf is the *standard* SVM approach.